# How can I do to see only day of the current month using a datepicker?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, datepicker

I am using React.js and here is the code for my datepicker :

```
<DatePicker dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy" selected={startDate} minDate={new Date()} onChange={date => setStartDate(date)} />
```

The problem is the following in the picture below :

[My datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5X0ZT.png)

If I go to december 2020 I see the last day of November and the first day of January ...

How can I do to remove that ?

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite the CSS of this class:

```
.react-datepicker__day--outside-month {
  color: transparent !important;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```